# Keycloak merge attributes from 2 user directories

Tags: keycloak, jira

For the project I am working on I need to delegate authentication of JIRA users to Keycloak. The credentials of these users are stored in a specific Active Directory. I successfully managed to login with a specific user account. However, the project has the requirement to receive the user's specific JIRA groups from a different LDAP server.

My question now is; is it possible to let Keycloak lookup information (groups) from another user federation and add it as a custom attribute to the user? It should basically merge the information from two user directories into a single user so I can use that in JIRA.

Thanks!